# Converting MySQL Date to Java Date : Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, date

I get a value of

> 2014-04-13

from mysql.

I used this code

```
String date = "2014-04-13";


try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    Date convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(date);
    Log.d("Date", convertedDate.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the conversion wont happen. it gives a parse exception and also the android app gets stopped.

I Want the output as

> 04 April, 2014

Comment: your date pattern & input String don't match...

Comment: Why are you getting a *string* from MySQL at all? What's the type in the database? And if it isn't a date column, *why* isn't it a date column?

Comment: What do u mean @Reimeus show me an example

Comment: @Ruch1234 `"2014-04-13"` is not in the format `"dd MMM, yyyy"`

Comment: @JonSkeet its in date data type. but json array gets it as string.

Comment: @ZouZou i want the outout as that. where i got it from a blog in a tutorial.

Comment: @Ruch1234: Where does JSON come into it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd MMM, yyyy", java.util.Locale.getDefault());

    java.util.Date convertedDate = readFormat.parse( date );

    String formattedDate = writeFormat.format( convertedDate );

    Log.d("Date", formattedDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}                   }
```

Comment: default locales should be used _very carefully_

Comment: @Salauyou why is that?